# SQL trigger throws error

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, triggers, alert, procedure

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AlertMail_tr]
ON 
[dbo].[MethodToLog_tbl]
AFTER INSERT 
AS      
BEGIN
DECLARE @LogId int
SET @LogId = (SELECT LogDataId FROM inserted)
if(SELECT Failure_flag FROM inserted)=1
begin
        exec [DB].[dbo].SendMail_prc
        @Command='EXEC CheckNew.dbo.FailureMail_prc @LogId'
        ,@MailPriority=1
        ,@MailRecipients='abc@xyz.com'
        ,@Subject='Alert-Failure'

end
END
```

I am getting this error :

> Must declare scalar variable @LogId.

Comment: Instead of SET i used SELECT and it worked.Thanks anyways for the answers. :)

Comment: I would suggest that you test this trigger by doing a mulitple record insert if they are possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Command='EXEC CheckNew.dbo.FailureMail_prc @LogId='+cast ( @LogId as nvarchar(100))
```

or

```
@Command='EXEC CheckNew.dbo.FailureMail_prc '+cast ( @LogId as nvarchar(100))
```

Also ,

put a *Value* in  `@LogId` **before** you exec the string query.

### edit

```
declare @tmp nvarchar(max)
set @tmp='EXEC CheckNew.dbo.FailureMail_prc '+cast (@LogId as nvarchar(100))



 exec [DB].[dbo].SendMail_prc
        @Command=@tmp
        ,@MailPriority=1
        ,@MailRecipients='abc@xyz.com'
        ,@Subject='Alert-Failure'
```

Comment: But the function requires that i send it as an integer

Comment: you are sending an integer. but before that it has to go through string statement.

Comment: @Sharmi the statement will look as `EXEC CheckNew.dbo.FailureMail_prc @LogId=5` and not `EXEC CheckNew.dbo.FailureMail_prc @LogId='5' `

Comment: Instead of SET i used SELECT and it worked.Thanks anyways for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

you @LogId variable doesn't exist on the scope of the EXEC command. 
It only sees what's inside it, so as far as it is concert, the line `DECLARE @LogId int` doesn't exist.

You need to pass the string already with the value of the variable on it.

```
declare @aux varchar(100)
set @aux ='EXEC CheckNew.dbo.FailureMail_prc '+cast ( @LogId as varchar(10)) 

        exec [DB].[dbo].SendMail_prc
        @Command=@aux
        ,@MailPriority=1
        ,@MailRecipients='abc@xyz.com'
        ,@Subject='Alert-Failure'
```

of course, correct the lengths as you seem necessary

Comment: Ya but instead of SET i used SELECT and it worked.Thanks anyways for the answer. :)